# JS: check if time doesn't exceed the maximum allowed from an array of intervals

Tags: javascript, date, time

The goal is to check, whether the selected date doesn't exceed the maximum time.

I have an array of time intervals. The maximum time is `toMinutes - 20 minutes`.

Below you can find my solution, which always returns `false`.

How can it be edited to match expected result, which is also specified below?

```js
const dateRanges = [{fromMinutes: 360, toMinutes: 600}, {fromMinutes: 700, toMinutes: 900}];
// "06:00 - 10:00", "11:40" - "15:00"

const minutesToHourFormat = (minutes) => {
  return new Date(minutes * 1000).toISOString().slice(14, 19);
};

const isWithinMinDate = () => {
  const selectedDate = "14:30";
  
  return dateRanges.every(({ toMinutes }) => {
     const minTime = minutesToHourFormat(toMinutes - 20);
      
     return selectedDate <= minTime;
  })
}

// Expected Result
// 14:30 -> true
// 14:40 -> false
// 14:10 -> true
// 9:50 -> false
// 9:30 -> true

console.log(isWithinMinDate(), 'res')
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. The definition of "maximum time" is going to be multiple, since you have multiple `toMinutes`, do you want to check if the given time is later than 20 minutes before the *earliest* `toMinutes`? Then it is normal you get `true`. Please explain exactly which logic you had in mind...

Comment: I've added expectedResult.  I need to check if selectedValue doesn't exceed both toMinutes

Comment: I don't think your logic is going to work, you're doing toMinutes * 1000 which in your case is 360*1000 and passing it as an argument for new date which expects timestamp. In your case new Date() will always return some date in 1970.

Comment: can you please explain what does 360 minutes mean? is that 360 minutes passed since midnight? if yes then I'd convert the 14:30 into minutes with the same logic and compare numbers together

Comment: I don't get it. Why should 14:30 return false when the toMinutes value is 15:00? That's more than 20 minutes. If that is expected then why 14:10 should return true, as it also is more than 20 minutes away from 15:00.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, my bad. I've edited post. If selected value is less than 20 minutes from toMinutes -> false. If selected value is more than 20 minutes from toMinutes -> true

Comment: ` every` will return true only if every item in your array passes the condition. in your case even if the conversion works correct you'd end up with
` 14:30 <= 10:00` this will make your `every` to return false all the time.

Comment: The *minutesToHourFormat* function is flawed. It seems you want to pass it a time value, which should be milliseconds so `minutes * 1000` should be `minutes * 6e4`, i.e. milliseconds in a minute, not milliseconds in a second: `minsToTime = mins => new Date(mins * 6e4).toISOString().slice(11,16)` (which is also why you're slicing the minutes and seconds not hours and minutes from *toISOString*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `every` call should verify against both limits, because the given time could be outside *any* interval, or when it is within 20 minutes for one ending interval, it would be still considered when checking against a later interval!

And I would prefer converting the selected time string to minutes, instead of doing the inverse:

```js
const hourFormatToMinutes = (fmt) =>
    fmt.split(":").reduce((h, m) => h * 60 + +m);

const minutesToHourFormat = (minutes) => 
    new Date(minutes * 1000).toISOString().slice(14, 19);

const dateRanges = [
    { fromMinutes: hourFormatToMinutes("6:00"), toMinutes: hourFormatToMinutes("10:00") }, 
    { fromMinutes: hourFormatToMinutes("11:40"), toMinutes: hourFormatToMinutes("15:00") }
];

const isWithinMinDate = (hourFmt) => {
    const minutes = hourFormatToMinutes(hourFmt);
    return dateRanges.some(({ fromMinutes, toMinutes }) =>
        minutes >= fromMinutes && minutes < toMinutes - 20
    );
}

for (const test of ["14:30", "14:40", "14:10", "9:50", "9:30"]) {
    console.log(test, isWithinMinDate(test));
}
```